# Windows: How change the view icons on the window lower right corner

Tags: windows, windows-10, window, user-interface

How I can change, say Details View icon to List View icon and Large Icons View icon to Tiles View icon ?

[image: View Icons Lower Right Corner]

I've searched everywhere and found nothing about it.

Comment: If you want to use Windows Explorer as a shell this cannot be done.

Comment: @Ramhound well I searching for a custom in registry, there must be some key value somewhere we can change for this.